# How can i bend this chainmail diagonally? The curve modifier is messing up!

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier

[image]

i have this chain mail i created by arraying a single link in the x and y direction, and then i rotated the resulting square 45 degrees. Origin is at world origin, arrays are not applied, all transforms applied as deltas to not mess up array.

I want to curve it diagonally along the curve, but the curve modifier freaks out and produces this horrible result! If I don't rotate the mail it bends it correctly but not diagonally, which is how I want it to bend. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: I quickly recreated this by arraying a torus, and I was able to get a nice bend by just changing the deform axis on the curve modifier. Do any of the other axis's give a better result for you?


Alternatively if its a smooth bend you want, any luck using a Simple Deform set to bend with the origin set to an offset Empty?

Comment: @McBrett i tried changing the axis but no matter what i choose it's all messed up and does not follow the curve or touch it at all